# What's the difference between @CrossOrigin annotation http.csrf().disable()?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, cors, keycloak

This question is related to [Disable Keycloak authentication for a specific url in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047154/disable-keycloak-authentication-for-a-specific-url-in-spring-boot)

I have a 3rd party dashboard which manages my front end through an iFrame. But it calls my search api directly through it's search widget. The code mentioned below does not solves the problem of CORS for this search API only and sends this error
[image]
, all the other API works smoothly.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(@Nonnull final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);

    http.csrf().disable();

    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health", "/error").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Now I added the following code on my controller and it started working:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://dashboard-url")
```

so,

1. Is this the correct way to do this ? Is there any pitfalls using this ?
2. What is the difference between these 2, what is missing from my previous approach.
3. I have 3 stages(dev/stage/prod) onto which I might need to add this @CrossOrigin annotation, any suggestions how to proceed. I can make use of the profiles but prod does not have specific *-prod* tag e.g. dev and stage has the following url dashboard-dev.com/dashboard-stage.com. But prod has dashboard.com only.

Comment: CORS and CSRF are completely different things. Did you read something about both? Wikipedia or Spring Security reference?

Comment: My knowledge about security is a bit limited. Are you suggesting that http.cors() above would not help with the error in screenshot above ?

Comment: No, I don't suggest it. You have an CORS issue and you already solved it with `http.cors()` and `@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://dashboard-url")`.

Comment: So to answer my first question, it is the right way to do it. Is this the only way to solve this issue. ?

Comment: Yes, it is the right way. No, it is not the only way. You could also use a CORS configuration instead of the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are doing is correct

Please check the  URL

1. https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#cors

If you are using Spring Security, make sure to enable CORS at Spring Security level as well to allow it to leverage the configuration defined at Spring MVC level.

So as per your coding, you have enabled cors at security using http.cors() and as there is no corsConfigurationSource (CORS filter ) been defined it uses the MVC level defined using @CORS(***)

However, if you want the values to be dynamic you can use as below with values fetching from external files based on env

```
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Can i get to know why is it negative?I mean  what is the correct solution .

Comment: The -1 from someone was a bit harsh. I would add that you can also use the @CrossOrigin annotation to define CORS settings at controller class/method level.